# How do I export a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to export a matrix `f` that is `double`. My data in `f` are real numbers in three columns. I want a `txt` file as an output with the columns separated by tabs. However, when I try the `dlmwrite` function, just the first column appears as output.

```
for k = 1:10
f = [idx', firsttime', sectime'];
filename = strcat(('/User/Detection_rerun/AF_TIMIT/1_state/mergedlabels_train/'),(files_train{k,1}),'.lab');
 dlmwrite(filename,f,'\t') ;
end
```

When I use `dlmwrite(filename,f,'\t','newline','pc') ;` I keep getting an error Invalid attribute tag: \t . I even tried 'tab' instead of '\t' but a similar error appears. Please let me know if you have any suggestions. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are not calling `dlmwrite` properly.  To specify the delimiter, you **must** use the `delimiter` flag, followed by the specific delimiter you want.  In your case, you use `\t`.  In other words, you need to do this:

```
for k = 1:10
    f = [idx', firsttime', sectime'];
    filename = strcat(('/User/Detection_rerun/AF_TIMIT/1_state/mergedlabels_train/'),(files_train{k,1}),'.lab');
    dlmwrite(filename,f,'delimiter','\t') ;
end
```

BTW, you are using the `newline` flag with `pc`, meaning that you are specifying carriage returns that are recognized by a PC. I suggest you leave this out and allow MATLAB to automatically infer this.  Only force the newline characters if you know what you're doing.

FWIW, the MATLAB documentation is pretty clear about delimiters and other quirks about the function: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html

Comment: Thank you, Its working now :) And thank you for such an easy explanation

Comment: It turns out that I have to split the columns by space with a specific precision format, in order to make it compatible to be used in another software. But when I try it as : dlmwrite(filename,f,'delimiter',' ','precision','%10.0f') ;  It seems that they are still separated by tabs.   Do you have any suggestions of what may be the reason?

Comment: Yes. I'd use `fprintf` instead. I'm on the road and not at a computer. When I come home, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hi again, I tried the following, it seems to work correctly now :  fileID = fopen(filename,'w');
         fprintf(fileID,'%d %d %d\n',f');
         fclose(fileID);     Could you please let me know if you have some other idea?

Comment: No that's exactly what I was going to suggest. I thought you needed a `%10f` formatting specifier for the numbers. Either way good job!

Comment: Thank you :) actually the numbers are all integers and I wanted them to be in non-scientific format.  But I realized that when using %10.0f, it appeared 4 spaces between them, while using %d its just one space.

Comment: Got it. Well I'm glad you figured it out!